# What is the best way to implement public key authentication in my automated root password change script?

Tags: linux, ssh, public-key

Here are some details about my setup...

Current environment:

- 40+ *nix systems managed by 6 admins
- Highly secure, closed network (no internet access)
- Regularly audited (all account passwords must be changed every 90 days)

Current procedures:

- Each administrator has a personal account with sudo access. These admin accounts are managed via Active Directory so password changes are not an issue
- Root account is also active for specific circumstances (i.e. admin account is locked out)
- When it comes time to change the root passwords, an admin will do so by SSHing into each system (40+)

I want to write a script to make the root password changing process more efficient and everything I've read indicates that the most secure way to go about it is by using public key authentication. So my question is: If I log in as root to SYSTEM_1 and set up the public/private key pairs between that system and SYSTEM_2, SYSTEM_3, etc, does that mean I will only be able to run the script from SYSTEM_1? Is this even a good idea security wise? Are there any other ways to script this that I am missing?

Comment: sorry, your question is about how to automate the password rotation process or which authentication method is more secure?

Comment: My question is about how to automate the process most securely. Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: how about writing expect scripts to log in and perform the changes? that's how Oracle OPAM does

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSA Authentication and expect script

Let's say you are executing expect script on system 1, create public-private key pair and store public key on all the other systems you have to login (system 2.....n)

Now you wont need a password when you ssh into those system.

Now you can use expect script to change password for either root or any other user. 
NOTE : usually expect interpreter is at     /usr/bin/expect
you can find this my doing "whereis expect"

I hope it helps.

Try to use this algorithm and post your results.

Comment: Once connected through RSA auth, is the information passed to the remote systems secure?

Comment: @kenster89 Yes it's secure.